# How to make eyeglass lens material

Tags: materials, shaders

I am trying to make a pair of eyeglasses but am having trouble with the lenses. I can't seem to make the lenses look right. I tried using the glass shader but it made the lenses look more like a mirror. I also tried the transparent shader but it just made the lenses invisible. How can I make a material that looks just like a glasses lens?

Comment: hello, you don't say if you use Cycles or Eevee, also maybe share what you've done so far so that we can see why your current material doesn't work? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I didn't remember this answer actually, I hope it will help the user, but it looks like you are 6 months late  ^^

Comment: yes but sometimes the questions look similar but the problem car be very specific and different

Comment: You're right, I vote too close too

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Material Properties panel and set Blend Mode to Alpha Hashed under Viewport Display -> Settings.

Alternatively, you can switch render engine to Cycles under the Render Properties panel.